# Does $i\hbar \frac{d \hat A }{d t} = [\hat A (t_0), \hat H]$ hold when $H$ is time-dependent, but $[H(t_0), H(t'_0)] = 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, time-evolution

It is known that - given in Sakurai, ch2.2, p83 - in Heisenberg's picture, for a Hamiltonian, $H$, independent of time, the time evolution of any operator $\hat A$ is given by

$$i\hbar \frac{d \hat A }{d t}  = [\hat A (t_0), \hat H].$$

Is this equality true when Hamiltonian is dependent on time, but $[H(t_0), H(t'_0)] = 0$ ? I have given an argument why it should be true, but it is correct, or is there any flaw ?

I tried the following argument;

Since 
$$A (t) = U(t, t_0)^\dagger A(t_0) U(t,t_0),$$
we have
$$\frac{d \hat A (t)}{ dt } =  D_t [U(t, t_0)^\dagger]AU(t, t_0) + U(t, t_0)^\dagger A D_t[U(t,t_0)] $$
, but since $\frac{i \hbar d U_t }{ dt } =  H(t_0) U_t$,
$$=\frac{ 1}{ i \hbar} [U_t A H(t_0) U_t -  U_t^\dagger H(t_0) A U_t].$$

In this case $U_t := U(t, t_0) = \exp{(\frac{-i}{\hbar } \int_{t_0}^tH(t') dt')}$, but since $[H(t_0), H(t'_0)]$, when we expand the exponential function as a Taylor series, and consider $H(t_0) U_t$, the $H(t_0)$ term will commute with every integral in the expansion, so $[H(t_0), U_t] = 0$, hence

$$\frac{d \hat A (t)}{ dt } = \frac{ 1}{i \hbar } [U_t^\dagger A U_t, H(t_0)] = \frac{1}{ i \hbar} [A(t), H(t_0)],$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is completely correct.

Consider an operator $A$ which is not explicitly time-dependent (it is constant in the Schrödinger picture) and the time-evolution with a possibly time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$.
Then, the time-evolution is
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} A_H(t) = \frac{1}{\mathrm i\hbar} [A_H(t), H_H(t)] $$
in general, where $H_H(t) = U(t,t_0)^\dagger H(t) U(t,t_0)$ is the Hamiltonian in the Heisenberg picture.
As you correctly noticed, $H_H(t) = H(t)$ in the case where $[H(t_1), H(t_2)] = 0$ for all times.

For completeness, let us also consider the situation where $A$ is explicitly time-dependent, i.e., $A = A(t)$ already in the Schrödinger picture.
The Heisenberg picture is defined as
$$ A_H(t) = U(t, t_0)^\dagger A(t) U(t, t_0) $$
and note that this is not the same as $U(t, t_0)^\dagger A_H(t_0) U(t, t_0)$!
Taking the derivative, we get an extra term from the product rule:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} A_H(t) = \frac{1}{\mathrm i\hbar} [A_H(t), H_H(t)] + \left( \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \right)_H . $$
Here, $\bigl( \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \bigr)_H = U(t,t_0)^\dagger \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} U(t,t_0)$ as you would expect.
Compare this with $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dt} = \{ f, H \} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ in classical mechanics ($\{\bullet,\circ\}$ is the Poisson bracket).

For reference, see e.g. Cohen-Tannoudji: *Quantum Mechanics* (complement G-III).

Comment: where did that $\frac{\partial A}{ \partial t}_H $ term come from  ?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused a little; if $H(t) = U^\dagger (t,t_0) H(t_0) U(t,t_0)$, and $[H(t_1), H(t_2)] = 0$, then $H(t) = H(t_0)$, so $H$ is independent of time. Also, if it is independent of time, trivially, $[H(t_1), H(t_2)] = 0$, so these two conditions are equivalent. This clearly show that there cannot be a case where $[H(t_1), H(t_2)] = 0$, but $H(t)$ is time dependent; however, in Sakurai's book, at the end of the page 70, there is such an explicit assumption.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I fixed a typo that was maybe confusing you. But I don't know where you got $H(t) = U^\dagger H(t_0) U$ from, it is wrong. You have to distinguish the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ in the Schrödinger picture and the Hamiltonian $H_H(t)$ in the Heisenberg picture, that's why I put a subscript "H".

Comment: even if it is wrong, how can you justify the term $\frac{ \partial A}{ \partial t} $ in that expression; that is what I'm failing to see.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I edited my answer again.

Comment: What is the difference between $H_H(t)$ and $H(t)$ ?

Comment: $H$ is Schrödinger picture, $H_H$ is Heisenberg picture.

Comment: Yes, but mathematically **and** physically, how they are different ? what is their difference ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88761/discussion-between-noiralef-and-onurcanbektas).

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in your time dependent $H(t)$ for $A(t)$ in the evolution equation, you get $\frac{dH(t)}{dt}=0$, so the set of equations

$i\hbar \frac{d \hat A }{d t}  = [\hat A (t_0), \hat H]$

$[H(t_0), H(t'_0)] = 0$

$\frac{d \hat H }{d t} \neq 0$

is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tonydo; it is probably  because I forget to take the derivative of $H$ wrt time.

Comment: Well, after going over the "proof", there is no need for the derivative of $H$ also, since the Sch. eqn, for the time evolution operator valid regardless of the time dependence of $H$.

Comment: This answer is only half-right. The equation derived by OP only holds for $A$ without explicit time-dependence, but they never claimed otherwise.

Comment: @Noiralef Are your emphasis on explicit/implicit time-dependence ? If so, regardless of its type, if a function is time dependent, it can be represented as both implicitly and explicitly time-dependent.

Comment: @onurcanbektas An operator has "explicit time-dependence" if it is time-dependent in the Schrödinger picture. In your question, $H$ is explicitly time-dependent and $A$ is not.

Comment: @Noiralef Why the equation that is derived hold only for $A$ without explicit time-dependence ?